# cast ? super T to T

Tags: java, generics

Is sure to cast `? super T` to `T`?

Example:

```
public void method(? super Date param)
{
    Date d = (Date)param;
}
```

I'm not able to do `Date d = param`. Why?

Comment: Your Syntax is invalid. Please post your full code and describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33246935/1466267

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow a tutorial on generics ;)

Here's what it should look like:

```
public <T extends Date> void method(T date){
    Date d = date;
}
```

You specify the generic type *before* the parameter input. I suggest taking the time to read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Are you sure that OP is able to use `extends` when he used the keyword `super` in his question?